# Evaluation of integral with cosine integral function

Tags: integration, contour-integration

Does anyone know how can I evaluate this integral

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_0^\infty dx\;e^{-x^2} \operatorname{Ci}(ax)
\end{equation}
where $\operatorname{Ci}(x)$ is the cosine integral function
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Ci}(x)=\int\limits_\infty^x dt\;\frac{\cos(t)} t
\end{equation}

Comment: *winter is coming*

Comment: Probably if I don't learn how to solve this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming $\text{Re}(a) > 0$ here.

Let $$J(a) = \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \operatorname{Ci}(a x)\; dx $$

Differentiating, we get

$$ J'(a) = \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \frac{\cos(ax)}{a}\; dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a} e^{-a^2} $$

Now we should expect $J(a) \to 0$ as $a \to \infty$, so

$$ J(a) = - \int_a^\infty J'(s)\; ds = -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \operatorname{Ei}(1,a^2/4) $$
according to Maple.  This can also be written using the incomplete Gamma function:
$$ J(a) = -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \Gamma(0,a^2/4)$$